# Erratic AWS lambda behaviour with typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm observing a very weird behaviour when uploading my code to aws lambda. 
Once the code is deployed and I hit the endpoint with postman, the first time will run fine. The second time I hit it will give me this error:

```
{
    "error": "Validation error"
}
```

If I then redeploy, it will work once and then break again. If I run it locally, it will never break

I have pin pointed the issue to a single line of code:

```
this._repo.save(user)
```

The model is saved in the database just fine, but I receive that error. Has anyone encountered such a problem? What could be the cause of this behaviour?

This is the code

```
  public signUp(event: APIGatewayEvent): Observable<APIGatewayProxyResult> {
    return this.register(event).pipe(
      concatMap(user => {
        const body = parseBody(event);
        //if we find a referrer we add a new entry in the db

        const createUserObservable = of(this.generateUserResponse(user, true));
        const saveReferralObservable = body.referrerId ?  this.referralService.save(user.id, body.referrerId) : of({});

        return combineLatest([createUserObservable, saveReferralObservable])
      }),
      map((res) => {
        return Response.ok(res[0].body, res.headers)
      }),
      catchError((err) => of(Response.errorResponse(err)))
    );
  }


 private register(event: APIGatewayEvent): Observable<UserInfosModel> {
    const body = parseBody(event);

    return this._repo.findBy({email: body.email}).pipe(
      map(user => {
        if (user) {
          throw new BadRequestError('This email is already registered');
        }
      }),
      concatMap(() => encryptPassword(body.password)),
      map(password => {
        body.password = password;
        return this.createUserModel(body, event.queryStringParameters);
      }),
      concatMap(user => this._repo.save(user))
    );
  }
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't know more without understanding what the code runs under the hood, however this is guaranteed to be not a typescript problem, but a javascript problem problem. Because typescript transpiles to javascript and only strips out the types; it doesn't change out the code is executed.

Comment: Post your code. Are you setting something in the global scope?

Comment: I'm not setting up anything globally, apart from the connection to the database, all the logic is inside the function. The funny thing is that it fails only when I save to the database, but when I retrieve, it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

When you run into this kind of problem, It's most likely your function is not idempotent.

Lambda does not guarantee clean start for your functions. It is a feature to re-use the previous execution container along with (old) temp disk space

Please check your function to see if it leaves something like unwanted variable in the context space, unclosed streams, leftover DBcontext and things like that

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/running-lambda-code.html

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the solution. 
I use the @Default decorator to generate a new uuid for every new model in sequelize. 
After reading about the context I realised that the uuid created would always be the same. So when the first model was created the uuid would remain in the context and any subsequent insert would use the same uuid up until a new context is run and a new one is generated. So rather than following sequelize-typescript @Default decorator, I used the beforeCreate hook to manually generating an id. That solved the issue.